# OAuth2 without login/pass in FastApi

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

How to perform authorization in FastApi without using login/password form, i.e it requires certain user data that is sent to a third-party service to check for the presence of a similar one there.

Comment: Any reason why you need to use the OAuth2 classes when you don't want to use the standard OAuth2 form fields? The `get_current_user` example from the examples are independent of the authentication scheme, and authorization would be left to you in either case - i.e. in your authentication route, authenticate the user there, perform required authorization in a separate dependency or in your get current user dependency.

Comment: @MatsLindh, well, to be honest, I dont precisely understand, how to implement my own callable bearer class (like OAuth2PasswordBearer and OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer) to get "authorize" button and perform required authorization in a separate dependency. My understanding was only enough to create a form in post(/token) and a small modification of the jwt token

Comment: i was trying to make ```get_current_user``` with dependency of my ```form``` class, but with this  ```get_current_user```  requires to fill form within its body (and because of it I should change it from get method to post)